# Covariance matrix computed based on a covariance function

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, correlation, covariance

I am reading [Chapter 4](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf) of [Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/). It says that a matrix $K$ whose entries are computed as $k_{ij} = k(x_i, x_j)$ where $k$ is a covariance function is a positive semidefinite matrix.

Consider the exponential kernel

$$
k(x_i, x_j) = k(|x_i - x_j|) = k(d_{ij}) = \exp\left(-\frac{d_{ij}}{10}\right) 
$$

and the matrix

$$
D = (d_{ij}) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 3 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 2 & 3\\
3 & 2 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 3 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}\right).
$$

I compute my potential covariance matrix $K$ by evaluating the kernel at the corresponding entries of $D$, that is,

$$K = (k_{ij}) = (k(d_{ij})).$$

The resulting matrix, however, seems to have one negative eigenvalue as shown in the following snippet of MATLAB code:

```
D = [ 0, 1, 3, 1;
      1, 0, 2, 3;
      3, 2, 0, 1;
      1, 3, 1, 0 ];

eig(exp(-D/10))

ans =

   -0.0314
    0.2156
    0.3078
    3.5080
```

I assume that I misunderstood the material given in that chapter, and I would be grateful if somebody could point out my mistake. Thank you!

Best wishes,
Ivan

Comment: Is $D$ supposed to be a matrix of distances? Because here, $d_{24}=3\gt1+1=d_{21}+d_{14}$, hence it is not.

Comment: The intuition behind $D$ is, yes, like a distance, but it was computed artificially without trying to satisfy any conditions of a metric. There are probably some additional requirements, which I am not aware of, for being able to do what I am trying to do here. Could you please explain?

Comment: If you are referring to (4.18) (for $\gamma=1$), indeed this yields a covariance function when $|r|$ in the formula is a distance since $r$ stands for $x_i-x_j$, but not for every set of "distances" $|r|$. This is why your matrix $D$ fails, I believe.

Comment: Yes, I see now. I very conveniently jumped over $|x_i - x_j|$ and  have been disregarding it thereafter. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I had been looking for was given in the comments by @Did:

Is D supposed to be a matrix of distances? Because here, $d_{24}=3>1+1=d_{21}+d_{14}$, hence it is not. If you are referring to (4.18) (for $\gamma=1$), indeed this yields a covariance function when $|r|$ in the formula is a distance since $r$ stands for $x_i−x_j$, but not for every set of “distances” $|r|$. This is why your matrix $D$ fails, I believe.